# Écrit-on « tous deux » ou « tout deux » ?

Tags: expressions, grammaire, pronoms, nombres

J'ai un petit doute en écrivant la phrase suivante :

> Ils ont tous deux donné leur accord.

J'ai retenu *tous* car je pense qu'il s'agit d'une ellipse pour *tous les deux*.

Pouvez-vous confirmer ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tu as raison, on écrit bien « tous deux ».

Quelques sources :

- [Deux — Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/deux/24907/difficulte)
- [Deux — Dictionnaire de l'Académie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/deux), section I. 1.
- [Deux — Trésor de la langue française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/deux), Section I. 2. a.